# JSLink field value form Display Form automatically includes a <div dir=""> element

Tags: jslink, template

I am using JSLink to override a TextArea column on SharePoint 2013, when I am trying to get the field value using `ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]` on display form, it warps the value with an div element `"<div dir="">`.

However, on New and Edit forms, `ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]` return the value correctly without the div element.

So can I get the value from field without `"<div dir="">` ? Thanks

```
(function () {
rendering functions
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    'Tile': { 'View': renenderTileField, 'DisplayForm': renenderTileField }

}
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

function renenderTileField(ctx) {
    LoadCssForFrom();
    var fieldVal = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    var html = [];
    html.push('<div class="col">');
    var content = generateHtmlForField(pickerObject, titleFieldVal);
    html.push(content);
    html.push('</div>');
    return html.join('');

}
}();
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery helps you:

```
$(ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]).text()
```

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. It was not some misunderstanding from my side. I roll backed my review.